# save many-to-many relationship in corresponding mapping-table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

in my Spring-Boot application i want to save a User-Role **many-to-many relationship** in a corresponding mapping-table in my database, but hibernate gives me an error message.

My **User.java** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;
  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  String username;
  String password;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
  private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

My **Role.java** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;
  String name;
  String description;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
          name = "role_users", 
          joinColumns = 
              @JoinColumn(name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
          inverseJoinColumns = 
              @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  )
  private Set<User> users;
}
```

My **run**-method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    //add new Roles
    Role roleA = new Role("Rolle A");
    Role roleB = new Role("Rolle B");
    Role roleC = new Role("Rolle C");

    //add new Users
    User userA = new User("FirstnameA", "LastnameA", "UsernameA", "PasswordA");
    User userB = new User("FirstnameB", "LastnameB", "UsernameB", "PasswordB");

    //add new Lists of Roles
    Set<Role> rolesA = new HashSet<Role>();
    rolesA.add(roleA);
    rolesA.add(roleB);
    Set<Role> rolesB = new HashSet<Role>();
    rolesB.add(roleA);
    rolesB.add(roleC);

    //add a list of roles in one user, two times
    userA.setRoles(rolesA);
    userB.setRoles(rolesB);

    //save both users in db
    userRepository.save(userA); //rolle AB
    userRepository.save(userB); //rolle AC

    //give each role the corresponding user
    Set<User> usersA = new HashSet<User>();
    usersA.add(userA);
    usersA.add(userB);
    roleA.setUsers(usersA);
    roleRepository.save(roleA);
    Set<User> usersB = new HashSet<User>();
    usersB.add(userA);
    roleB.setUsers(usersB);
    roleRepository.save(roleB);
    Set<User> usersC = new HashSet<User>();
    usersC.add(userB);
    roleC.setUsers(usersC);
    roleRepository.save(roleC);

}
```

Hibernate gives me an error message on that:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projekt_gra`.`role_users`, CONSTRAINT `fk_roleusers_user` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I have the construction from [this site](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/) and it works with it, but in my code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always pass this problem, by rewriting the 2 @ManyToMany relations to @OneToMany to a new entity which deliveres me the table inbetween.

A good reason is that when I have @ManyToMany relations, I can never really easily get whatever I want, as I get carthetic products. Having this table inbetween as an entity totally removes this problem for me.

So, to wrap up:

- You already have your **User**, and your **Role** class, those are almost OK
- Create a new Entity: **UserRole**, with properties: User user and Role role
- Change the two @ManyToMany in **User** and **Role** to @OneToMany's to your new @Entity **UserRole**
- Add the relations in **UserRole**: 2 @ManyToOne relations to **User** and **Role**.

You now got the problem gone, and extra: a posibility to query on the relation UserRole.

Comment: you mean like [this](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-extra-columns-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)?

Comment: Not completely. You have your User, and your Role class. Change the ManyToMany to OneToMany's to your new Entity: UserRole. Create that with 2 ManyToOne relations to User and Role. You now got the problem gone, and extra: a posibility to query on the relation. (I will add this to my answer to clarify more)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I asked a friend in the company i work actually and he helped me. I posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk-Jun I am facing an issue with the approach which you mentioned can you please take a look at this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959365/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-many-to-many-relation-is-inserting-null-in-link-entit

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!
Thanks to a friend, i solved my Problem. If it interests somebody: i tried to save a user in the repository first, then the role. And because the role doesn't exist in the moment i want to save my user, Hibernate gave me that error message.

Comment: So you still persisted with many to many? and Now you created a role before creating a user?

Comment: yes. i have a many-to-many relationship in the User.java, but added another annotation: the **@JoinTable**